# Можно ли с помощью aiogram обрабатывать гиперссылку

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли обрабатывать гиперссылки в боте? Я имею ввиду, чтобы при клике на определенное слово в тексте бот исполнял какую-то логику, как, допустим, при нажатии на кнопку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте к сообщения инлайн-кнопки, привяжите к ним обработчики. Радуйтесь.

При клике на ссылку в тексте - её обрабатывает приложение телеграм. Никак иначе. Даже когда вы ссылку ставите через инлайн-кнопку - даже тогда человек при нажатии на кнопку просто переходит по ссылке.

Пока вы не описываете какая логика вам нужна - никто вам ничего не ответит путного. Учитесь правильно задавать вопросы.